# Extending SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 SQL tables: User, Student, Professor and Publication.

- User has the common columns for any kind of user;
- Student has columns specific for a student;
- Professor has columns specific for a professor;
- Publication is only for professors.

So I have:

```
create table dbo.[User] (
  Id int identity not null
    constraint PK_User_Id primary key clustered (Id),       
  -- Other user columns
)

create table dbo.Student (
  UserId int not null
    constraint PK_Student_UserId primary key clustered (Id),        
  -- Other student columns
)

create table dbo.Professor (
  UserId int not null
    constraint PK_Professor_Id primary key clustered (Id),      
  -- Other student columns
)

create table dbo.Publication (
  Id int identity not null
    constraint PK_Publication_Id primary key clustered (Id),        
  UserId int not null
  -- Other student columns
)

alter table dbo.Student
  add constraint FK_Student_UserId foreign key (UserId) references dbo.[User](Id);

alter table dbo.Professor
  add constraint FK_Professor_UserId foreign key (UserId) references dbo.[User](Id);

alter table dbo.Publication
  add constraint FK_Publication_UserId foreign key (UserId) references dbo.Professor(Id);
```

**QUESTION**

Should I have a column Id as PK in Professor and Student tables?
And make, for example, (Id, UserId) as the PK of Professor (Same for student)
Then Publication would reference Professor.Id and not Professor.UserId.

I am asking this because it sounds strange to have Publication to reference UserId from Professor table which can be confusing when I will have more tables.

Could someone please advice me on this?

Comment: Can a user be more than one professor, i.e. is _professorness_ a measure of, say, how many courses the user teaches? Can a user be both a student and a professor?

Comment: I would recommend having a primary key in all your tables. I would also recommend not using the habit of a generic column ID as the primary key for every table. This has two challenges, one is the name is totally ambiguous. The second is that the name of the column changes between tables and that is a pain to work with. Make it UserID in every single table. Same with StudentID and ProfessorID.

Answer (score 0):

In your current schema arrangement and without knowing your use cases (programmatically), one could make the argument that you don't need the Id identity columns for any of the extension tables.  I assume this would be a 1 to 1 relationship to the User table anyway, so you'd at least want a unique constraint on the UserID columns, which you'd get by making it a PK anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is a 1 to 1 relationship that is why I used UserId as PK. This covers the requirements ... the point is if I should have an extra column as PK anyway so other tables relate to this one with an ID of Professor so it is more evident that is related to Professor only and not to all Users in User table.

Comment: I, personally, would not use the extra space to make the design self-documenting, though I can certainly understand someone doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Things I like to consider are:

- Can a professor ever become a different user ?
- Is it possible for a professor to exist without an user ?
- Is it possible for a single user to be two professors (multiple disciplines?)

If so, why wouldn't you give every professor an unique Id (ProfessorId), and only create a foreign key to the User table (UserId, you could call this UserFk).

In the publication table you can reference the professor by his/her id and call this one ProfessorFk. This way you create very efficient references between tables. The publication table than also gets a single PublicationId as primary key.

Correct me if i'm wrong, i don't know your use case. But it would seem reasonable that a professor can have multiple publications, but a publication can also be written by multiple professors ? This would mean you need an extra table between publication and professor for the n-n relationship.

About creating a professor key that is a combined key (Id, UserId). I personally dislike combined keys, if you want to reference this professor from your publication table you need two columns.
This would also suggest you can have multiple professors for the same user, if so, go for the single Id option.

This means i would create the following setup:

- User Table

  - UserId
- Student Table

  - StudentId
  - UserFk
- Professor Table

  - ProfessorId
  - UserFk
- ProfessorPublication Table

  - ProfessorFk
  - PublicationFk
- Publication Table

  - PublicationId

So, it partly is based on what you want to be able to do with your data, and partly just your preference.

Comment: Your suggestion could make sense but in my case a Professor is always the same user ... It is a 1 to 1 relationshipt ...Professor and Student tables are only extensions of User table. And a publication can only be written by a professor, in this case.